# Question about AC-RL circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

A source power with $$v(t)=5\sin(\omega t)\text{ V}$$ and frequency 1kHz is connected thought an \$RL\$ parallel circuit. The maximum current is 5mA and the resistor current is 4mA. 
What is the value of the inductor?

We did:

Il=Vin/jwL
thus:

L=(5;-90)/j6283 
L= 0.8H 
Is it correct?

Ir=Vin/R 
Ir=5v/5^10-3 
Ir=1250ohms

Comment: We did: 

L=(5;-90)/j6283

L= 0.8H

Is it correct?

Ir=Vin/R
Ir=5v/5^10-3
Ir=1250ohms

Comment: Just to know if my answer is correct.. Can you help?

Comment: No, it isn't correct.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Tweed. Whats the problem? Why ist't it correct?

Answer (score 1):

First, find the current in the inductor, keeping in mind its phase relationship with the current in the resistor. Here's a hint: It's 3 mA (not 1 mA). The problem was specially constructed to make this step easy. Can you explain why?

Next, knowing the voltage and current, calculate the AC impedance of the inductor.

Finally, knowing the impedance and the frequency, calculate the value of the inductor.

Comment: Thats exactly what I think I did. But I didn't understand why you say my answer is wrong.

Comment: Yeah.. I think.. if my resistor current is 4mA, obviously my inductor current is 1mA. Because the question says that my max current is 5mA. 

After I got the current, I found the Ir=5v/5*10^-3

Comment: @AlfredoAlfredes, the resistor current and inductor current are in quadrature, i.e., the inductor current is phase shifted 90 degrees from the resistor current so, *you can't add them together like you've done*.

Comment: Ok. The quadrature is shifted 90 degrees. But what it means? Dave Tweed have said that my inductor current is: 3mA.. But in my knowledge, if my max current is 5mA and the resistor current is 4mA, Why my inductor have 3mA? 3mA + 4mA = 7mA. More than the max 5mA of my all circuit.

Please, how can I find my inductor current? Can you explain with numbers? Im trying, but I can't find logic in all this answers..

Comment: Wikipedia says me that the RL circuit, I have my IL current with this:

IL = (Vin) / (jWL) 

I have two variables that I dont have values.. IL and L.. How can I find IL with this formula?

I know.. the inductor have -90 with resistor. And if my resistor is: 5V/4*10^-3 = 1250 ohms. My complex number is: 1250(Real);0(Imaginary) 

Will my inductor have (REA);(-90). Ok.. but How can I find the 3mA of my real value like Mr. Dave Tweed said?

Comment: OK GUYS!!!!

I found the solution to find 3mA!!

Itot = SQRT( Ir^2 + Il^2 )

5mA = SQRT( 4mA^2 + Il^2 )
5mA^2 - 4mA^2 = Il^2
Il = SQRT(0,00009)
Il = 3mA

Yeah!! Thanks guys!

Comment: www.isu.edu.tw/upload/52/35/files/dept_35_lv_2_4170.pdf

PAGE 17 !

Comment: @AlfredoAlfredes, write a summary of what you've just learned as an answer and then accept it.